Ведь иногда мы пишем одно, а читаем и, соответственно, произносим — ​другое. Нужно ли тире перед "другое"?
Ведь иногда мы пишем одно, а читаем и, соответственно, произносим — ​другое. Нужно ли тире перед "другое"?
Можно предположить, что там пропущено "что-то (совсем)".

В этом предложении лучше поставить интонационное тире для обозначения паузы, что допускается правилами:
Ведь иногда мы пишем однО, а читаем и, соответственно, произносим — ​другОе.
Пояснение

Тогда фраза будет более понятна, так как ударением выделены слова, которые нужно противопоставить: одно — другое.

Сравнить: Ведь иногда мы пишем одно, а читаем другое.


В менее распространенном варианте тире не ставится, так как нет необходимости подчеркивать парные слова.

Есть еще вариант оформления со вставкой (парное тире), мне он кажется более подходящим:

Ведь иногда мы пишем одно, а читаем — и соответственно,  произносим — ​другое.
